# Can hardware issues cause segfaults and core dumps?

Tags: hardware-failure, segmentation-fault

I bought a second hand computer a few weeks ago and I've been having a few issues.

At first, I was installing Arch Linux and everything went smoothly until I tried to launch X at which point, X would segfault. (more details here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/686604/cannot-launch-xorg-on-intel-graphics-i5-8250u-computer).

So I tried re-installing Arch from scratch and this time it went fine and I can launch the GUI without any issues.

Since then, I've noticed a few errors. I often get segfaults and coredumps in places where I never would in my old computer. This includes programs crashing (e.g. MS Teams), booting k8s failing, Brave causing SIGILL errors, programs not compiling (e.g. Ruby 2.7 or pmount) and more seemingly unrelated issues.

I can still use the laptop for my day-to-day work, but once in a while something like this will happen.

I'm not sure what could be causing all of this, but my best guess is it being hardware related. Could a faulty memory stick be causing these issues?

For what it's worth I ran the BIOS diagnostics and everything passed fine.

Comment: Run [MemTest86](https://www.memtest86.com/) for many hours, at least overnight.

Comment: Yes  this could be hardware or driver related - or a combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely yes.

Memory errors can result in code changes making execution streams pass invalid instructions, data or branch to random areas.

Hardware faults can return garbage or invalid results, making a driver choke, fail or otherwise act in an entirely unexpected manner. If given garbage data a driver could forward it on to the hardware which could potentially use DMA to copy to or from wrong areas of RAM, for example, and so cause major problems with other parts of the system.

Any device failing can cause a cascade of errors and they can be difficult to nail down.

[Memtest86](https://www.memtest86.com/) can find memory errors, but other devices such as a GPU failing or other hardware acting odd due to internal faults or soldering faults can be nearly impossible to diagnose. Due to their tight and often non-replacable components laptops can be even more difficult to find the root cause.